# How to remove black glue from Arches paper border?

Tags: paper, watercolor

Just got an Arches block of watercolor paper, parer sheets are glues together on 4 sides with a BLACK glue.

It seems a really good paper but i can't find a way to remove the black glue on the border once i take the piece of paper off the block.

They could use transparent glue.

Comment: There's not really any reason to remove it, assuming you're going to mat and frame your finished work. You're never going to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have the same problem with watercolor-blocks that are glued on the edges, only that you see the remains of the glue better when the glue is black. What I usually do to remove the glue is one of the following.

1. Cut the edges with a sharp scalpel (or another sharp knive) preferably with the help of a metal ruler.
2. Lay the paper flat on a hard surface and scratch the edges (e.g. with your nails) until the glue is gone.

I dont think there is a non-invasive way to remove the glue, as it is made for holding the paper to the block really tight - even when wet.